# whats the difference between export.create and router.post?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, postman

I've seen 2 ways of creating a restful API.

1: "export.create" and once you add code on postman you have to add it in json format.

2: "router.post" which I understand that's using express and when you add code on postman you add it using 'x-www-form-urlencoded'

What's the difference?

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    if(!req.body.certifications,
       !req.body.memberships,
       !req.body.hobbies,
       !req.body.interests) {
        res.status(400)
        res.json({
            error: "Bad Data"
        })
    } else {
       Basic.create(req.body)
        .then(() => {
            res.send("Basic Added")
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send("Error: " + err)
        })
    }
})

------------------------------------------

exports.create = (req, res) => {
    var customer;
    Customer.create({
       firstname: req.body.firstname,
       lastname: req.body.lastname,
       age: req.body.age 
    }).then(createdCustomer => {
        // Send  Created Customer to client
        customer = createdCustomer;

        return Address.create({
           street: req.body.street,
           phone: req.body.phone
        })
    }).then(address => {
        customer.setAddress(address)
        res.send('OK'); 
    })
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exports.create` just exports the method as part of a [commonjs](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-module-system-commonjs-require/) module, that can then be used with `router.post` in another file.

Something like this:

```
const { create } = require('./the_file_name.js');
router.post('/', create);
```

Comment: Makes sense. Do you know why people use different types of format (JSON), (x-www-form-urlencoded) add data?

Comment: That's probably an entirely different question. Honestly, it depends entirely on what you expect your clients to send to you, though. Different types have different pros/cons. If you don't have any specific requirements for performance / data size / client restrictions, JSON seems to be a standard default at this point. Easy to implement, easy to read, widely supported, good enough size.